# how to read an int array with input elements separated with special characters

Tags: java

I have been trying to take the array input by separating the values with `'#'`.Can anyone of you help me to get through this?

I have used the split function but it is not working. Is there any possibility of solving this problem?

Comment: Please add your code and input to the question

Comment: I suggest you show us a minimal example of what you are trying to do, added to the question and we can help you fix it.

Comment: please share the code and explain the question more clearly.

Comment: To helping you out need minimum code.just share what you did to achieve

Comment: Post code you have and expected answer format.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share code, input and expected output.

Comment: the split method will work just fine, but you 'll end up with an array of String objects. You'll need to create an array of ints with the same lenth, and parse the contents of your first array to the second one

Answer (score -1):

Take your and start appending it to String then:

```
 StringBuffer str;
//loop it
str.append(arr[i])
String[] arrOfStr = str.split("#");
After that convert to Integer and use
```

Comment: seeing as his seperation symbol is '#', your code will fail. Seeing as the OP states split doesn't work for him, providing him with another way it won't work is not a good answer. You may want to wait until we know for sure why it doesn't work for him, before trying to point out where he went wrong.

Comment: since he is trying to put split method for integer,it is failing,please try with # symbol it is working ,you need to wait for his reply before down voting

Comment: You may want to check the comments. so far, all you've done is: "look at your code, it works", while you haven't seen the code, so you can't know whether or not it works, or where it is he goes wrong. this answer should 've been a comment, not an answer

Comment: Let see,Based on my assumption,It is fine,let him see if it works for him well and good.